# Match single element in list of lists

Tags: scala

If I have a list of the form **List[Any]** like this one

> val list = List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8)))

how do I then write a match statement that distinguishes between

1. Single element of any non list type (i.e. **2** from above)
2. Elements that are lists (i.e. **List(1,1)** and **List(3, List(5, 8)** from above)

or in pseudo scala

```
list match {
  case x:"single non-list element" => // do something with single element x
  case y:"where y is a list"       => // do something with list y
}
```

the usual **head::tails** matching does not work as **head** can be of type **Any** which includes other lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list foreach { 
  _ match {
    case x:List[_] => // list
    case _ => // anything else
  }
}
```

should work i guess

Comment: this will work except you need a type parameter for List, so in this case you want List[Any] probably

Comment: @Sean, thanks, yes i missed out on providing the type! edited the code now.

Answer (score 5):

```
val (lists, nonlists) = list partition {case (x :: xs) => true case _ => false}

lists: List[Any] = List(List(1, 1), List(3, List(5, 8)))
nonlists: List[Any] = List(2)
```

Comment: or `list partition (_.isInstanceOf[List[_]])`

Comment: Returns `false` for empty lists.